# How to achieve dynamic lightning for day/night earth planet

Tags: lighting, drivers

I cant get dynamic lightning. I have used drivers to set up this, however, once I add the night texture it still shows on parts that I have lights. Here is my node setup:

[image: https://imgur.com/kD0SdBV]

[image: https://imgur.com/FX3CTWp]

I have been following Blender Guru's tutorial on the earth planet up until the point where he makes static maps for day/night (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y - min. 29:00) and then used this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvx4pYGK0a0)  to create dynamic.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)