# Object emission only on illuminated side

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes, emission

I'm trying to simulate an image taken by a telescope of objects close to the moon. So far, I have managed to have the moon correctly illuminated, and using the lightpath node, it emits light without blowing the textures.
[image]

The problem now is the dark side of the moon is not very dark. To solve this problem and make the scene more realistic, I would like only the portion of the moon illuminated to emit light. Is there any way to basically create a mask of the illuminated portion to use it as a factor into the mix shader for the light emitted?

Comment: This was asked just today https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288377/is-there-a-way-to-change-emission-strength-based-on-the-amount-of-light-hitting and as been asked multiple times before already

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116394/how-to-make-texture-appear-only-in-dark-spots https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167948/is-it-possible-to-have-a-node-value-correspond-to-how-much-light-is-hitting-that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166465/how-to-achieve-dynamic-lightning-for-day-night-earth-planet https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/how-can-i-mix-two-materials-based-on-incoming-light